# Chef Server installation issues

Tags: chef-infra

I have been trying to install chef server (chef-server-core-12.1.0-1.el6.x86_64.rpm), on my CentOS 6.5 machine using this guide: http://docs.chef.io/server/install_server.html#standalone 
This is a test environment, hence I Do not have a FQDN but the IP address is resolvable. After I run chef-server-ctl reconfigure, I try to create a user using:

```
[root@xxx-xxx-xxx-xxx ~]# chef-server-ctl user-create myusername myfirstname mylastname myemail mypassword --filename /root/myfile.pem
```

I fill appropriate details in the above command, but I keep getting this error:

```
ERROR: Connection refused connecting to https://127.0.0.1/users/, retry 5/5
ERROR: Network Error: Connection refused - Connection refused connecting to        https://127.0.0.1/users/, giving up
Check your knife configuration and network settings
```

The ngnix service is down all the time, cannot get it to start. After going though the logs:

```
 tail -f /var/log/opscode/nginx/current 
 2015-07-01_10:59:00.69218 nginx: [emerg] invalid number of arguments in "server_name" directive in /var/opt/opscode/nginx/etc/chef_https_lb.conf:3
```

The file chef_https_lb.conf is as follows:

```
server {
listen 443;
server_name ;

access_log /var/log/opscode/nginx/access.log opscode;
```

I am not sure whats going wrong. Anyone shed some light please?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In case somebody stumbles across this searching for an answer ( Just as I did ).
The problem is you need to set the FQDN of the server other than localhost.

Example on Centos 6.6

In your /etc/hosts file, the top line that reads ( or similar to )

```
127.0.0.1 localhost
```

Change localhost to the hostname you have set for your server (`/etc/sysconfig/network`)

```
127.0.0.1 servername.com
```

Restart your networking service

```
$: service network restart
```

When you run the following commands on the servers terminal

```
$: hostname
$: hostname -f
```

They should both output "servername.com"

Run `chef-server-ctl reconfigure` to rebuild the ssl certificate for the chef server.

You should be able to add your admin user / ORG and the opscode-manage web interface

Comment: Note: I was able to get the same results by just *adding* the output of `$ hostname` to the top line of `/etc/hosts`. Thank you for this answer!

Answer (score 6):

In my case it was nginx failing to bind to port 80 because apache2 was already using it. So my **chef-server-ctl tail nginx** looks like this

```
# chef-server-ctl tail nginx                                                                                                                                                  
==> /var/log/opscode/nginx/internal-chef.access.log <==

==> /var/log/opscode/nginx/error.log <==
2016/07/20 12:22:29 [emerg] 28912#0: listen() to 0.0.0.0:80, backlog 511 failed (98: Address already in use)
2016/07/20 12:22:29 [emerg] 28912#0: listen() to 0.0.0.0:80, backlog 511 failed (98: Address already in use)
2016/07/20 12:22:29 [emerg] 28912#0: listen() to 0.0.0.0:80, backlog 511 failed (98: Address already in use)
2016/07/20 12:22:29 [emerg] 28912#0: listen() to 0.0.0.0:80, backlog 511 failed (98: Address already in use)
2016/07/20 12:22:29 [emerg] 28912#0: still could not bind()
```

So I looked at the **nginx.conf** file and commented out the server that listen to port 80 - seeing as it redirects to 443 anyway. I then restart nginx and **chef-server-ctl user-create ...** works :) e.g.

```
# vi /var/opt/opscode/nginx/etc/nginx.conf
 ...
    # We support three options: serve nothing on non_ssl_port (80),
    # redirect to https, or actually serve the API.
    #     server {
    #       listen 80;
    #       access_log /var/log/opscode/nginx/rewrite-port-80.log;
    #       return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    #     }

# chef-server-ctl restart nginx
ok: run: nginx: (pid 32236) 0s
# chef-server-ctl user-create username fname sname username@example.com password --filename username.pem
```

Comment: Perfect! Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to disable SELinux so Chef can bind its services to various sockets/ports. You may have to disable qpid, too.

See:

http://docs.chef.io/server/install_server_pre.html

especially:
http://docs.chef.io/server/install_server_pre.html#selinux

Comment: Hello, thanks for your reply. I have set the SElinux to permissive mode and I don't have qpidd installed on my CentOS. Overtime I check the status of the chef services: 
down: nginx: 0s, normally up, want up; run: log: (pid 4378) 11394s
nginx is always, it starts when I call chef-server-tcl start, but goes down again.

Comment: am not sure if this is the issue - nginx being down. Why does it go down?

Comment: because you another webserver is already running on port 80/443/...?

Comment: #netstat -anp | grep :80 gives:

tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:8000              0.0.0.0:*                   LISTEN      24166/beam.smp
there is nothing running on 443.

Comment: reverse DNS broken non-existing?

Comment: I don't have a domain name - its a VM which has an IP.

Comment: I have just updated the question, if you can take a look again?

Comment: You didn't read the server requirements. You need a working FQDN setup. http://docs.chef.io/server/install_server_pre.html#hostnames

Comment: Am sorry, but the requirements clearly say the IP address can be used test environment. Or have I got it wrong?

Comment: have you specified the IP address as hostname?

Comment: what does `hostname -f` return?