# Setting up a chef server - chef-server-ctl commands not working(404 not found)

Tags: cmd, chef-infra, redhat

I'm trying to set up my own chef server on a hosted VM on a cloud environment, the problem is that whenever i try to execute one of the `chef-server-ctl` commands like `user-create` or `user-list` I get the following error:

```
ERROR: The object you are looking for could not be found
Response: <!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//IETF//DTD HTML 2.0//EN">
<html><head>
<title>404 Not Found</title>
</head><body>
<h1>Not Found</h1>
<p>The requested URL /users was not found on this server.</p>
<hr>
<address>HTTP_Server at 127.0.0.1 Port 443</address>
</body></html>
```

I seen that on the `<address>` tag it points to `127.0.0.1`, but my server its another IP.

First I  edited the `/etc/opscode/chef-server.rb` and on `server_name` I used the fully-qualified domain name (FQDN), nothing changes.

Then, on `/etc/hosts` file I had two lines:

```
127.0.0.1 localhost
999.999.999.999 mydomain.com <- this is the ip I use for ssh
```

So, following [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31139017/chef-server-installation-issues) response, I replaced the localhost with mydomain.com, didn't change the IP address.

`$: hostname $: hostname -f` both have the same outputs `mydomain.com`

Now, when I try to run sudo `chef-server-ctl reconfigure` I get:

```
FATAL: SocketError: getaddrinfo: Name or service not known
```

IDK what else to try...

---

Answer (score 0):

`127.0.0.1` is localhost, meaning it is always reachable from anywhere. If you are trying to get Chef Server to listen only on the public interface and *not* localhost, I suspect that will break many things and would be unsupported.